# SVG path attribute d to e.g. geoJSON

Tags: javascript, json, svg, openlayers, geojson

I've lot of geometries in a SVG. To be able to edit them in an Openlayers vector layer i'd like to convert the svg geometries e.g. to a geoJSON format, so that I can easily add them to the Openlayers layer.

FROM:

```
path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="G0W9Q7bC" d="M29.68 -30.10l-12.94 9.61 220.96 157.25 67.98-166.86-276.00 .00"/>

path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="G0W9Q7bA" d="M1223.26 349.19l-167.71 93.84 265.54 117.80-70.46 71.27 145.87 .00 .00-53.18-173.24-229.73"/>

path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="G0W9Q7bz_0" d="M1281.16 265.33l .00-111.81 115.34 .00M1396.50 265.33l-115.34 .00"/>
```

TO:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              568420.74334458,
              121173.52026851001
            ],
            [
              568420.74334458,
              135550.45067237
            ],
            [
              598372.6816859602,
              135550.45067237
            ],
            [
              598372.6816859602,
              121173.52026851001
            ],
            [
              568420.74334458,
              121173.52026851001
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a js framework which can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to use OpenLayers. You can use [d3](http://d3js.org/) to draw a map. d3 also, has a [lot of methods](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/) that can help you in the conversion.